# How to run Node.js that is bundled with Electron?

Tags: node.js, electron

I'm using the `better-sqlite3` NPM module which uses a native extension to talk to SQLite from an Electron app.

In order for this to work with Electron, I need to rebuild the native extension so it is compiled with the same version as the Electron app.

```
"postinstall": "electron-rebuild -f -w better-sqlite3",
```

However, now if I want to write a Node.js CLI tool that ships with the application, it's going to use the globally installed Node.js which might be the wrong version:

```
Error: The module '/Users/chet/Code/brain-web/object-system/node_modules/better-sqlite3/build/Release/better_sqlite3.node'
was compiled against a different Node.js version using
NODE_MODULE_VERSION 85. This version of Node.js requires
NODE_MODULE_VERSION 72. Please try re-compiling or re-installing
the module (for instance, using `npm rebuild` or `npm install`).
```

So my question is how do I run `node`, but specifically reference the Node.js binary that is shipped with `electron`?

**Edit 1**: It looks like you can use `./node_modules/.bin/electron index.js` to run any Node.js script. However, the application doesn't exit gracefully and errors don't surface in the CLI.