# Is there a way to run javascript in VSCode without Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to run js in VSCode using a school-issued laptop, and they don't allow me to download Node.js. Is there another way to run js in VSCode?

I've tried searching around for alternatives but all the tutorials I've seen just tell me to download Node.js

Comment: It depends on what APIs you want to use. Browser is can be run in a browser.

Comment: You can use glitch or jsfiddle

Comment: If you can't install Node locally, I highly recommend something like https://codesandbox.io  where everything is online and you get an almost complete VS Code experience.

Comment: You could rent a server, install node.js there, and connect vscode to it remotely. Very similar to an "online IDE", possibly a little better dev experience in vscode than in the browser for advanced uses. I wouldn't recommend this if you're just learning. What is your goal?

Comment: Actually you already installed nodejs with vscode, it uses it internally (electron). See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66003842/1048572) for an example

Answer (score 0):

The short answer would be no (in VS Code).

Javascript needs a **runtime environment** to be executed, like Node JS, or V8 engine in Chrome Browser.

Alternative solutions: Using online IDE or in your browser, right-click -> inspect -> Console tab -> paste your code and click enter to execute